# ASP.net File Uploader in UpdateProgress sending over empty

Tags: c#, ajax, file-upload, updatepanel

I am trying to send some data over to write into our SQL server.  I added an update panel so the user knows that it is processsing.  Before I added the updatepanel all the data was sending over fine, after I add in the UpdatePanel, the Text boxes send over fine but the FileUpload control fails to send anything over.  Any ideas?  Thanks.  Here is my aspx code

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
       <h2>   
        Upload Your File
        </h2><br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploader" runat="server" />
        <br /><br />
        Please Enter a Patient ID: <asp:TextBox ID="PatientIDTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br /><br />
        Please Enter a Draw Date: <asp:TextBox ID="DrawDateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender
        ID="CalendarExtender1"
        TargetControlID = "DrawDateTextBox"
        runat="server">
        </asp:CalendarExtender><br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ProcessFileBtn" runat="server" Text="Process File"  
        OnClick="ProcessFileBtn_OnClick" /><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="TestLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br /><br />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="blur">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="progress" class="center">
            <center>
                <i>Update in progress. Please wait ...<br />
                </img src="Images/MyAjaxLoader.gif" />
            </center>
        </div>  
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: I had the same problem and I just tested this so I know it will work for you .. set the following attributes to the following for the Button that actually does the processing when you click on the Upload button 
CausesValidation="False"
PostBackUrl="#" UseSubmitBehavior="False"

Comment: you must be doing something wrong...it does work for me..